# Raid alert catch python script need to have Nagios logic added

Tags: python, python-3.x, nagios, nagiosxi

Can someone please help how can I  add Nagios logic to catch alerts to my below python script?

I tried adding the sys.exit(0) and sys.exit(1) for all OK and CRITICAL, Or Please Let me know what I should do, So that this script when run Nagios catch the 0,1,2 and display the message.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import os, sys


#Check python present or not
#  dnf install python3.6-stack
# export PATH=/opt/python-3.6/bin:$PATH

def check_MegaRaid():
   # Next script
   failed=subprocess.run(["sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -AdpAllInfo \ -aALL | grep -i 'Failed Disks' | awk -F':' '{print $2}'"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
   failed_status = failed.stdout
   print("failed_status is",failed_status)
   critical=subprocess.run(["sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -AdpAllInfo \ -aALL | grep -i 'Critical Disks' | awk -F':' '{print $2}'"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
   critical_status = critical.stdout
   print("critical_status is",critical_status)

   if failed_status.strip() and critical_status.strip() == "0" :
       print("Raid check all OK" )
       sys.exit(0)
       #return 0

   else:
       print("CRITICAL")
       sys.exit(1)
       #return 1




def check_raid():
   process=subprocess.run(["sudo /sbin/mdadm --detail /dev/md127 | grep -i state | grep -w clean, | awk -F',' '{print $2}' |sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' "], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
   output = process.stdout
   check_process=subprocess.run(["sudo /sbin/mdadm --detail /dev/md127 | grep -i state | awk -F':' '{print $2}' |sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' "], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
   check = check_process.stdout
   if output.strip() == 'degraded':
       print("Raid disk state is CRITICAL ",output)
       #return 1
       sys.exit(1)

       
   elif check.strip() == 'clean':
       print("Raid check all OK")
       #return 0
       sys.exit(0)
   else:
       print("sudo /sbin/mdadm --detail /dev/md127 cmd not found : This  is an dataraid machine")
       check_MegaRaid()

#Check whether system configure raid
process=subprocess.run(["sudo cat /GEO_VERSION | grep -i raid | awk -F'Layout:' '{print $2}' | sed 's/[0-9]*//g' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
raid_value = process.stdout

if raid_value.strip() == 'raid':
   print("System configure Raid functions")
   check_raid()
else:
   print("There is no raid configured in this system")
   exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html in case you're interested.

0 is OK
1 is Warning
2 is Critical
3 is Unknown

So the first thing you need to do is replace your `sys.exit(1)` with a `sys.exit(2)`

I would also replace that final `exit()` with a `sys.exit(3)` to signal that it is an Unknown exit, which will you help you identify mis-configured services in the UI.

You'll also want to indicate the status first, a typical one-line plugin output will look like:

```
STATUS: message | perfdata
```

But it doesn't look like you're using performance data, so change your critical exits to be prepended with the characters `CRITICAL:` and your OK statuses with `OK:`.